# What are the advantages of using http with express

Tags: node.js, http, express

I've been using the Node.js express module for some time now, without ever using the http module to listen to the port.

I'm wondering what are the benefits of using:

```
app = express();
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

over

```
app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
```

My guess is that it's something to do with being able to set http settings such as `maxSockets` etc, but is there any other reason people do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen:

> The `app.listen()` method is simply a convenience method.

Here's the `listen` definition:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

Notice it passes its arguments to the server's `listen` call, so you can still sett http settings like `maxSockets`.

It also says, "if you wish to use HTTPS or provide both, use the technique above." The technique above it refers to is:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

So it seems one of the most common reasons not to use `app.listen` is if you want to have an https server.

I suppose you might need a reference to the return value of `http.createServer` for some reason, in which case you wouldn't want to use `app.listen`.

Comment: So apart from needing to use HTTPS, there is no real benefit to it?

Comment: Right. HTTPS seems to be about the only thing `app.listen` can't do.

Answer (score 3):

`express` is a layer on top of `connect` which is a layer on top of `http`.

## HTTP Interface API `http`

The [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) API Comes from Node. Only provides the basic HTTP functionality out the box.

- networking
- request, response
- events
- listening

## Middleware Layer `connect`

[Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) is a middleware framework for node, which allows you to write modular HTTP apps. It provides a bunch of middleware out of the box

- middleware
- static middleware
- bodyParser
- cookieParser
- compress
- csrf

## Web Application Framework `express`

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) provides an additional layer on top of connect, which allows you to do even more stuff, and actually build real applications with it. Most notably, it provides you with routing.

- routing
- template engine support
- configuration
- file upload abstraction

Comment: I've been using Express for some time, and the routing is really powerful. So, apart from needing to use HTTPS (as Trevor mentioned) there isn't much reason for me to use the HTTP module?

Comment: well, using it directly is rarely needed, as connect and express provide powerful abstractions on top of it.