# angularJS with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs

at last time I have learn use AngularJS and NodeJs, but I have a few problems.

First: 
I'd like loading.. for instance index.html or other file, now I do this manual and simplest how I can, but even then I have problem with type file which are include in index.html I receive:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:...

How can I correct this ? 
below code.

```
    'use strict';

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var render = function(response, fileName, code, httpCode){
  var code = code || 'utf8';
  var httpCode = httpCode || 200;

  fs.readFile(fileName, code, function(err, data){

      if(err) { return console.log(err); }
      response.writeHead(httpCode, {'Content-type': 'text/html; charset='+code});
      response.write(data);
      response.end();
  });

};


http.createServer(function(req, res){
    render(res, 'index.html');
}).listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running');
```

html:

```
 <!doctype html> <html class="no-js"><head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title></title>
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="styles/main.css">
     </head><body></body></html>
```

Can I use nodejs server with gruntjs ? if yes, how I can do it ?
Do somebody know any tutorial only angular + node ? it's mean I know quite good angularJS, but I can't use it with nodeJS..

Comment: why don't you try to use a view engine / express combination?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your browser requested a css file and you returned a file with the MIME type text/html. You would have to handle all the possible types of files (js, html, txt, css, ...).

I would recommend you to use an existing module like express, which will save you a lot of time. After installing express, initalize a static file server by doing following:

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Hmm okey, probably I understand :) but I have one more question maybe two.. is exist some alternative to express or this is most popular solution ? and perhaps do you have some good tutorial for me or any introduction ?

Comment: I have not used any alternatives yet but I think express is the most popular module. It is also being developed and improved constantly. The express website is very well documented: http://expressjs.com/. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is how my folder structure look like of Angular JS + Node JS (with Express JS)

```
ProjectTitle
|_app
  |_bower_components
  |_images
  |_scripts
  |_styles
  |_views
  |_index.html
  |_favicon.ico
|_routes
|_test
|_.bowerrc
|_.jshintignore
|_.jshintrc
|_bower.json
|_Gruntfile.js
|_package.json
|_README.md
|_server.js
```

3 imp things to notice here

/app - contains angular static app including all its dependant styles, scripts & images

/app/script - angular javascript files

/server.js - node js web server code, here is sample code

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app'))); // here you are mentioning which directory should be static directory for the project, in this case 'app'
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Start node js server using

```
$ node server.js
```

It will start express server, and you can access it by typing in browser window

```
localhost:3000
```

It will be good to look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and install [Angular Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). This is just to setup proper angular js project without error. If you have your own structure thats fine.

Comment: Thank you for reply :) I use Yeoman :) and my files/directory structure is very similar to yours. And this solution was very good as long as I learn angularJS and I wrote some simple app's, but now when I want include to my project nodeJS I can't reconcile all ;\ hmm I don't use express and I never read about this.. so, my question whether Can I use nodeJS + angularJS without express ?

Comment: And I'd like run server.js by gruntJS, because auto-refresh is very important for me.

Comment: There are benefits of using express js over just node js. Nodejs has bunch of core packages, express js a framework build upon those to make things simpler for further development. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690352/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-http-with-express) you will get some idea about it.
More on that, to get auto-refresh feature, you can use [Supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) or [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), which will make your development easier